# Check LIMIT 2 in a subset of ranges through PHP Programming from mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, understand what information i do have.

- Database Structure has one table named as `NUM`, columns are:

  - num_id `PRIMARY_KEY [AUTO-INCREMENT]`,
  - num_from and num_to `CONSTRAINTS [two columns form a UNIQUE_VALUE]`,
  - num_qty `DEFAULT [Qauntity is 1]`
- User enters two `inputs`, which i get through `POST` method and working fine getting the values:

```
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to   = $_POST['to'];
```

- Pre-checks(i have done successfully) before inserting a row in database:

  - Input values should be from the set of `whole-numbers`
  - Value of `$to` should be greater OR equal than value `$from`
  - Difference between `$from` and `$to` should not be greater than 30

---

```
**PRE CHECKS I AM UNABLE TO IMPLEMENT:**
```

SUM should not be greater than `2`. For example if user inputs values:

```
$from = 100;
$to = 125;
```

AND the database has values:

```
num_id | num_from | num_to | num_qty
1         100       120       1
2         103       131       1
```

1. THE VALUE `SHOULD NOT GET INSERTED`
2. AND THE ABOVE RULE SHOULD ALSO HOLD TRUE IF USER ENTERS THE VALUES DYNAMICALLY FROM ANY RANGE
3. BUT I AM NOT ABLE TO STOP THE ABOVE EXAMPLE INPUTS TO GET INSERTED AS THE FROM AND TO VALUES ARE DIFFERENT IN DATABASE BUT RANGES DO MATCH SOMEHOW, THAT IS WHY I DON"T WANT THE VALUES TO GET INSERTED

---

This is all the information i have, please do inform if any information needs to be changes to make the question more understandable

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS duplicate FROM tablename WHERE column-from >= $from and column-to <= $to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First of Thanks to "Malik Asif"

`$qty= $_POST['qty'];`

```
$qryString="SELECT SUM(num_qty) FROM num WHERE ";
for($i=$from;$i<=$to;$i++){
    if($i==$to){
        $qryString.= " ('" . $i . "' BETWEEN num_from AND num_to)";
    }
    else{
        $qryString.= " ('" . $i . "' BETWEEN num_from AND num_to) OR";
    }

}
$qtysum = mysqli_query($conn, $qryString);
$totalSum=$qtysum->fetch_row();
$sumIs = ($totalSum[0] + $qty) ;
if($sumIs > 2){ echo "error";}
else{ INSERT Query }
```

Comment: `" . $i . "`   --> -->  `'" . $i . "'` **non-object error**

Answer (score 0):

Try this(will update if some question becomes more clearer):

```
SELECT  anyColumnNameWhichWillBeSameInPossibleDuplicateEntries, COUNT(*) AS ENTRIES
FROM    tableName
WHERE   column_from > $from AND
        column-to < $to
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: result is only one. but data already 100-120, when entry 99-121  duplicate is 100, 101, 102, .........120  with use php

Comment: Can you please explain, what am i not being able to understand @A.Sang . Divide your question into sections, so that it becomes easier for us. **1** What are you trying. **2** What is the problem being faced. **3** and at end tell what you want ?

Comment: Share ColumnNames for easiness so that the duplicacy values could be checked on the basis of there values @A.Sang

Comment: sir, in html input field  from, to,  when post with php store data to MySQL  column from and to

Comment: if from and to --> 100 and 120  and every numbers only 2 times allowed

Comment: so i extra column total default 1

Comment: i stop limit with "sum(total) as total where from = $from